# the usage of "affect" and "depend on"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases, phrase-meaning

> *COVID-19 pandemic will end someday, but how much it* ***affects*** *the
> humanity **depends on** preventive measures like wearing masks, washing
> hands frequently, keeping a safe distance from others, etc*.
>
> *Let's practice social distancing and lower the risks of getting
> infected.*

Now, it's a fact based on much research that wearing masks, maintaining social distancing and washing hands frequently will slow down and decreases the active COVID-19 cases.

**1.** I am unsure about how I used the word **affect** in the paragraph above. I used it to show two meanings: **Less COVID-19 cases** (wearing masks etc.) and **More COVID-19 cases** (not wearing masks etc.). Is this use of word correct in this sense?

**2.** I'm also uncertain about this phrase: **depends on**.

What I want to say is if we wear masks and do other things, it will help us reduce the COVID-19 cases but if we don't, that number will increase.

But for some important reason, I don't want to write it specifically. At the same time, I'm also hoping what I've written also conveys the same meaning without giving incorrect (like wearing masks will increase cases) information.

To verify whether I'm correct in this type of use or not, I found this similar sentence in Oxford Dictionary:

> **depend on/upon sth** (not used in the progressive tenses) to be affected
> or decided by sth
>
> *Does the quality of teaching depend on class size?*

In the sentence above, let's assume a large class gives better quality education and a small one gives poor education. So now, without specifying exactly this, the question clarifies both things! I hope you got my point.

But I'm not sure about the way I've used "depends" in the passage. Is it conveying what I want to say?

---

Given these two doubts above, somehow I'm feeling what I've written might mean that wearing masks, social distancing, etc. will create more disease rather than lessening it.

**So finally, did I use those words accurately or have I given incorrect/false information?**

Comment: You described some "preventive measures", none of which are normal behaviour. Why do you think someone will take that to mean the opposite? Aside: "affects the humanity" should be "affects humanity", being a mass noun.

Comment: @WeatherVane I apologize in advance, my English is weak, I couldn't get your comment. Can you please elaborate? Yes I understand wearing masks and other things are not normal behaviour usually. I don't get full comment though.

Comment: You wrote "preventive measures like wearing masks, washing hands frequently, keeping a safe distance". That is a clear statement, saying those measures will help to prevent the spread of this virus.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah you are right. That means what I have wrote seems okay.

Comment: “the humanity” in your quotation is not English. You can’t use an article here. What was your source? Are you quoting it correctly? Should you really be posting on English Language Learners?

Comment: Listen, there are lots of grammar mistakes in the question and a few in the quoted passage. Dealing with all the errors, small and large, would take up a considerable amount of time. I've fixed the worst errors, and tried to clarify your question.

Comment: Main question - _affect_ is a verb, and it's used correctly in the question, as currently edited. _Depends on_ is also used correctly in the question, as currently edited.

Comment: Fewer cases, not less cases.

Comment: You should only ask one question per post